# How to convert a all possible pair matrix to indices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix of all possible pairs of the elements of a vector, like
1 1
1 2
2 1
2 2
Now I want to convert these matrix to indices like (1,1) (1,2) (2,1)etc. I would now like to use these indices to index elements from a second array B, or B(1,1),B(1,2) etc. How to do that without loops?

Comment: if you have a matrix like you describe, then each row is your index,

Comment: So matrix(1,:) is (1,1)? So then if I want to extract the (1,1) element of another matrix B, B(matrix(1,:)) will give me that (B(1,1)?

Comment: already you changed the question. edit that you want to extract values from a second matrix based on these indices...

Comment: on a side note, you'd want to use linear indexing with  `ind2sub`, or just flatten the matrix using the (:) operator

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is my trick. If you like it, please mark it as the answer.

Trial>> A = magic(4)

A =

```
16     2     3    13
 5    11    10     8
 9     7     6    12
 4    14    15     1
```

Trial>> B = A'

Trial>> B(:)

ans =

```
16
 2
 3
13
 5
11
10
 8
 9
 7
 6
```